# Loading Postgres functions with dependencies

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I'm using quite a few Postgres functions (both sql and pl/pgsql) in a particular application.  Some of the sql functions depend on other sql functions, e.g.

```
create or replace function my_function ()
  returns table (a text, b text) as
    $$
      select * from my_other_function();
    $$
  language sql;
```

For `my_function` to load properly, `my_other_function` has to be loaded first, else I get a `my_other_function does not exist` error.  To manage this, I have been manually ensuring that `my_other_function` *does* get loaded first, but it would be nice not to have to do that.

In other words, is there a way to load all of my functions without regard to order and somehow check that all the necessary dependencies are available (function objects) after the fact?

I'm using Postgres 9.6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `SET`[`check_function_bodies`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-CHECK-FUNCTION-BODIES)`= false;` prior creating your functions to suppress the error.